# Using the same ViewController h and m files for 2 View controllers in Story Board

Tags: iphone, xcode

So I pretty much built my first app(single view) but i've now decided I should add a little "about/info" button and just give a tiny amount of information on how to use the app and a website to go to.

I wasn't sure about the best way to go about this but storyboards seemed really convenient. A user here answered my question about adding a storyboard to my existing project which seems to work.

Now one question is can I use my current viewcontroller h and m files for the second view (the about screen). I suppose it would technically work if I set the Viewcontroller to the same one as my  primary app view.

the only thing this second view is going to have is text and a button to go back. Is it OK to set the connections in the storyboard and just let them use the same Viewcontroller files or is this a big no-no?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is recommended you use a different view controller for each view. In case of a static view controller in which the user doesn't interact with the view except maybe for navigation (which can be handled in the storyboard in many cases), I would just leave that view controller as a generic `UIViewController`, not a subclass.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use the same view controller to control more than one view, however, from what I understand, that doesn't seem like good practice in your case

For instance, if you had similar views with almost identical outlets (say the views have the same UI widgets such as buttons, titles but their layouts vary significantly) you co[uld create a separate view for each different layout and use a single view controller. But from what I understand, in your case, those two views will have different outlets (buttons, labels, etc.)

For this reason, I'd suggest creating a new view controller. Then when you want to show this second view, you will have to present it from your active view controller. I'd highly recommend you read tutorials on view controllers in Apple developer resources. But very quickly, I'd suggest the following

```
UIViewController *vc2 = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"View2" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]
[self presentViewController:vc2 animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And to go back to your main view, you'll have to dismiss this second view controller

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Of course, they don't have to be animated, you can set them to NO.

Comment: Thanks. It's just that my second view will have no outlets really, just a button and some text. I thought i'd get away with one View Controller but I suppose anything more and I will need 2? Do I need to do all of the above programatically? When i make the connections and set the animation settings in the storyboard, does it not do that automatically?

Comment: Yes you're right, storyboards are there to make all of this automatically for you. If there's no interaction in the second view, then you don't really have to create a second view controller. Just leave it as is (as Scott mentioned below)

Comment: Thanks, going forward i'll def take your advice in mind and use different viewcontrolers.